# "Serial" does not name a type -> How to solve this problem?

Tags: serial

I'm trying my best to solve this problem but it didn't changed

The red line was drawn on the last Serial.println */

```
int cds = A0;
int led = 12;
int trig1 = 2;      // Left Trig
int trig2 = 3;      // Right Trig
int trig3 = 4;      // Front Trig
int trig4 = 5;      // Upside Trig
int echo1 = 6;      // Left Echo
int echo2 = 7;      // Right Echo
int echo3 = 8;      // Front Echo
int echo4 = 9;      // Upside Echo
int vib1 = 10;      // Left vib
int vib2 = 11;      // Right vib 


void setup() {
        pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

        pinMode(trig1, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(trig2, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(trig3, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(trig4, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(echo1, INPUT);
        pinMode(echo2, INPUT);
        pinMode(echo3, INPUT);
        pinMode(echo4, INPUT);
        pinMode(vib1, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(vib2, OUTPUT);

        Serial.begin(9600);   
}


void loop(){
  long duration1, value1;
  long duration2, value2;
  long duration3, value3;
  long duration4, value4;

  // Ultra Sonic Sensor Part1
  digitalWrite(trig1,LOW);                           // Trigger Output
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig1,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trig1,LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn(echo1,HIGH);                   // Read Pulse Duration
  value1 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration1);     // Count Distance
  delay(10);

  // Ultra Sonic Sensor Part2
  digitalWrite(trig2,LOW);   
  delayMicroseconds(2);       
  digitalWrite(trig2,HIGH);    
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trig2,LOW);
  duration2 = pulseIn(echo2,HIGH);
  value2 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration2);
  delay(10);

  // Ultra Sonic Sensor Part3
  digitalWrite(trig3,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig3,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trig3,LOW);
  duration3 = pulseIn(echo3,HIGH);
  value3 = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration3);
  delay(10);

  // Ultra Sonic Sensor Part4
  digitalWrite(trig4,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig4,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trig4,LOW);
  duration4 = pulseIn(echo4,HIGH);
  value4 =  microsecondsToCentimeters(duration4);
  delay(10);

  //Commend Part (Vibration motor)

  // Print Out Value  
  Serial.print(" dist1 =");
  Serial.print(value1);
  Serial.print("(cm)");
  Serial.print(" dist2 =");
  Serial.print(value2);
  Serial.print("(cm)");
  Serial.print(" dist3 =");
  Serial.print(value3);
  Serial.print("(cm)");
  Serial.print(" dist4 =");
  Serial.print(value4);
  Serial.print("(cm)");
  delay(10);
  //

  // Initialize PIN Mode
  digitalWrite(vib1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(vib2,HIGH);

  // 진동모터1,2,3
  if (  value4<60  or  value3<60)
  digitalWrite(vib1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(vib2,LOW);

  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(vib1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(vib2,HIGH);

  if (0< value1 && value1<60)
  digitalWrite(vib1,LOW);

  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(vib1,HIGH);

  if (0< value2 && value2<60)
  digitalWrite(vib1,LOW);

  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(vib1,HIGH);
}

// Function of Count Distance

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds/29/2; 
}

        int cdsValue = analogRead(cds);

        Serial.print("cds =  ");
        Serial.println(cdsValue);

        if (cdsValue < 38 ) {
                digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        } else {
                digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be a lot easier to read and find mistakes in if you formatted it. I see that you did that in the IDE, but in your question, you need to highlight all of the code, then click the "{}" button to make it look like code in your question.

When I pasted your code into my IDE and auto-formatted it, the answer was immediately clear: after the function `microsecondsToCentimeters()` you have written some code that is not inside any function. C and C++ don't allow that. The error message wasn't very helpful - the compilers easily get confused by our mistakes - but in this case, looking at the formatted code made it clear.

*All of the executable code in a C or C++ program (Arduino IDE uses C++) must be inside a typed and named function.* Since that is what the compiler was looking for, it seems to have interpreted the word "Serial" as a function type, but no type was defined with that name.

I'm not sure where you intended the lines from the end of `long microsecondsToCentimeters()` to go, but they need to be inside of a function, somewhere.